# Symfony2 File Found Class Was Not In It

Tags: php, symfony, service, autoload

This is my first question, besides I'm not english-native speaker, so sorry in advance for newbie mistakes...

I'm starting with Symfony2, and I've been facing an autoload problem for a couple of days, i'm getting crazy..

I'm just trying to use a PHP class inside my DefaultController of my AppBundle. I've read the way of doing this is by creating a service in my config.yml and giving a namespace to that class that matches.

Symfony tells me that it does found the file but the class is not in it, the exact error is:

> The autoloader expected class "Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon" to be defined in file "/srv/www/lol.com/public_html/priceget/symfony/src/Priceget/CollectorBundle/Crawler/Amazon.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

And my class is just this:

```
<?php

namespace Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Amazon
{

    public function getAll()
    {
        return new Response('l0l');
    }
}
```

In my DefaultController I'm calling it like that:

```
<?php

namespace Priceget\CollectorBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $amazon = $this->get('amazon.crawler');
    }
}
```

And my config.yml piece:

```
services:
    amazon.crawler:
        class: Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon
```

I've already tried to:

- Empty cache
- Restart apache
- Extend the class to Controller? :-Z

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong, rename it:

from: `namespace Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon;`

to: `namespace Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler;`

Comment: By doing this, it returns File not found, autoload error. Btw, my folder structure is: src/Priceget/CollectorBundle/Crawler/Amazon. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you have "Amazon" folder and "Amazon.php" file in it then you need to change service class definition to: `Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler\Amazon\Amazon`

Comment: I dont, I missed the .php piece :P The file structure is: src/Priceget/CollectorBundle/Crawler/Amazon.php and if I get rid of 'Amazon' system raises a: FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Priceget\CollectorBundle\Crawler' not found in /srv/www/domain.es/public_html/priceget/symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

Comment: You were 100% right, the problem was that im so stupid that i was getting rid of the Amazon at the config.yml ^^ So that Exception..

Answer (score 5):

This error also occurs if you do not put `<?php` in the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what's said by Igor, you obviously have to change the FQN class name in the service declaration (YML) if you want it to work.

Comment: Amazon.php class is in: src/Priceget/CollectorBundle/Crawler/ by changing the namespace as Igor suggest, Symfony raises a Class not found error. Maybe I'm missing some basics? What's the meaning of FQN? (sorry for newbie questioning)

Comment: FQN stands for "Fully Qualified Name", this means the class name with the namespace. It's only a matter of changing the classname in both places: in the class declaration itself (php) and in the service declaration (yml) :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit misleading, it also happens if you don't extend your class correctly. In my instance I tried to extend a repository with an incorrect FQN:

```
class FilesRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
```

should have been:

```
class FilesRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
```

Notice the missing backslash (`\`).