# How to get user object inside form Repository in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I am developing a web app on Symfony. I have 2 entities that is question about, "Line" and "Dosier".  So, 1 dosier can have many lines.
Now I'm implementing the CRUD for the Line entity, so Line entity has a "dropdown" with all Dosiers from DataBase. 
The problem is that in dropdown are all dosiers from any users, but I need in this dropdown to have just options that has user_id = currentUser_id.

So, my controller action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/add-line", name="addLine")
 */
public function createLineAction(Request $request)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $user = $this->getUser();
  $line = new Line();
  $form = $this->createForm(LineType::class, $line);

  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
      $em->persist($line);
      $em->flush();

   return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
  }

  return $this->render('AppBundle:default:formLines.html.twig', array(
      'form' => $form->createView(),
  ));
}//create dossier action
```

My LineType (form builder)

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class LineType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')->add('dosier')
            ->add('dosier', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Dosier',
                'query_builder' => function($repo) {
                    return $repo->dosiersOfCurrentUser();
                },  
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Save',
                 'attr'=> array('class'=>'btn btn-success submitButton') 
                 )
            );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Line'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_line';
    }


}
```

My Line.php (entity)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Line
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="line")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LineRepository")
 */
class Line
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dosier", inversedBy="lines")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dosier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $dosier;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Loan", mappedBy="line")
     */
    private $loans;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loans = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Line
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add loan
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Loan $loan
     *
     * @return Line
     */
    public function addLoan(\AppBundle\Entity\Loan $loan)
    {
        $this->loans[] = $loan;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove loan
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Loan $loan
     */
    public function removeLoan(\AppBundle\Entity\Loan $loan)
    {
        $this->loans->removeElement($loan);
    }

    /**
     * Get loans
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getLoans()
    {
        return $this->loans;
    }

    /**
     * Set dosier
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Dosier $dosier
     *
     * @return Line
     */
    public function setDosier(\AppBundle\Entity\Dosier $dosier = null)
    {
        $this->dosier = $dosier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dosier
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Dosier
     */
    public function getDosier()
    {
        return $this->dosier;
    }
}
```

and my repository :  DosierRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DosierRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function dosiersOfCurrentUser() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('dosier')
            ->where('dosier.userId = 1 ')
            ->orderBy('dosier.name', 'DESC'); 
    }
}
```

How can I get the current user, or at least the current user id, to make a query like ... select from Dosier where  dosier.user_id = $???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller where you are buiding your form you need pass the user object to your form type

```
$tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$form = $this->createForm(new LineType($tokenStorage), $line);
//... other stuff
```

Now in your form type recieve this tokenStorage object and retrieve user object and pass to your repo function

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
//.. other use statements

class LineType extends AbstractType
{

    private $user;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $userId = $this->user->getId();
        $builder
            ->add('name')->add('dosier')
            ->add('dosier', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Dosier',
                'query_builder' => function($repo) use($userId) {
                    return $repo->dosiersOfCurrentUser($userId);
                },  
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Save',
                 'attr'=> array('class'=>'btn btn-success submitButton') 
                 )
            );

    }
}
```

In repo apply your filter

```
class DosierRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function dosiersOfCurrentUser($userId) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('dosier')
            ->where('dosier.userId = :userId ')
            ->setParameter('userId',$userId)
            ->orderBy('dosier.name', 'DESC'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. Everything is looking fine, except that error : The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Form\LineType" to be defined in file "/home/computer/project/src/AppBundle/Form/LineType.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
If I put my LineRepository or DosierRepository on folder Form it gives me the same error, or if I change the directory adress in entity/Loan.php ... same.

Comment: @new_newB1e may be something wrong with your name spaces or class name have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080796/symfony2-file-found-class-was-not-in-it and similar one by google

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I just now observed that in this multiple files... my LineType.php doesn't have a namespace statement.
Everything works fine, thank you for your help!